# cannot read image url imported from json file

Tags: json, react-native

```
// Json

{
  "image": "./images/restaurants/ding.jpg",
}

// React Native

import data from './data.json';
<Image source = {require(data.image)} style = {{ width: 98, height: 22 }} />
```

I am trying to load a picture from a local Json file. But I am getting the following error

```
calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require(_data2.default.image)`.
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: As the error states, it needs to be a string. So you need to declare a string literal

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 3):

require() takes only 'literale string' so you can't use variable.

so you can write :

```
const image = require('./image.png')
<Image
  source={image}
/>
```

but you can't write :

```
const image = './image.png'
<Image
  source={require(image)}
/>
```